# Execute bash command if wireless network is deleted?

Tags: macos, bash, plist

As part of a plist I'm writing for OS X, I need to execute the "say" command if a wireless network is successfully deleted using:

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork
```

If a network isn't deleted, it echos:

```
Network (network name) was not found in the preferred networks list
```

I currently have:

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en1  &&  say "Network deleted"
```

(where `en1` is the network interface name),
but that still says "Network deleted" even if a network is not deleted.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `networksetup` does not behave very well and returns `0` regardless the error message. This code will print the return code `0` in both cases:

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en1 ; echo $?
```

The solution is to parse the output:

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en1 2>&1 | grep -q "was not found in the preferred networks list" && say "Network deleted"
```